# Tuning Garbage Collection parameters in Java

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have a server java component which has a huge memory demand at startup which mellows down gradually. So as an example at startup the memory requirement might shoot unto 4g; which after the initial surge is over will go down to 2g. I have configured the component to start with memory of 5g and the component starts well; the used memory surges upto 4g and then comes down close to 2g. The memory consumed by the heap at this point still hovers around 4g and I want to bring this down (essentially keep the free memory down to few hundred mb's rather than 2g. I tried using the MinFreeHeapRatio and MaxFreeHeapRatio by lowering them down from the default values but this resulted in garbage collection not being triggered after the initial run during the initial spike and the used memory stayed at a higher than usual level. Any pointers would greatly help.

Comment: [This presentation](http://www.springsource.com/files/uploads/all/pdf_files/news_event/Inside_the_JVM.pdf) helped us a great deal to figure out memory settings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I ask why you are worried about freeing up 2 GB of ram on a server?  2GB of ram is about $100 or less. If this is on a desktop I guess I can understand the worry.

If you really do have a good reason to think about it, this may be tied to the garbage collection algorithm you are using. Some algorithms will release unused memory back to the OS, some will not. There are some graphs and such related to this at http://www.stefankrause.net/wp/?p=14   .  You might want to try the G1 collector, as it seems to release memory back to the OS easily.

**Edit from comments**
What if they all choose to max their load at once?  Are you ok with some of them paging memory to disk and slowing the server to a crawl? I would run them on a server with enough memory to run ALL applications at max heap, + another 4-6GB for the OS / caching. Servers with 32 or 64 GB are pretty common, and you can get more.

Comment: I have several such components run on a server providing various services so 2g spread across several components leads to a fair bit of non utilized resource.

Comment: You are right; however as I said the spike takes place only at start up and the server would have enough memory to take up the entire load; but there should be a way to configure the components in such a way that they give up the memory once the initial spike is over.

Comment: Did you try using G1 as I suggested?

Comment: You can buy a server with 64 GB for £2.5K and 96 GB for £3.5K

Comment: @Peter amazingly, especially in the world of Virtual Machines, Memory and Disk space have now become scarce commodities again. And the "Xen Masters" are getting stingier and stingier since Blades are NOT cheap, especially if you don't have any more slots for them. It's remarkable how much these cheap resources cost when people treat them as a cheap resource. And I'm sure Scorpion would happily take your £3.5K server to solve his problem, since you seem to be just handing them out.

Comment: thanks bwawok for the link; this (http://www.austinjug.org/presentations/JDK6PerfUpdate_Dec2009.pdf) was also pretty useful.

Answer (score -1):

You have to remember that the JVM reserves virtual memory on startup and never gives it back to the OS (until the program exits)  The most you can hope for is that unused memory is swapped out (this is not a good plan)  If you don't want the application to use more than certain amount of memory, you have to restrict it to that amount.

If you have a number of components which use a spike of memory, you should consider re-writing them to use less memory on startup or use multiple components in the same JVM so the extra memory is less significant.

Comment: Unless the documentation for Java 7 actually says it releases memory to the OS, I wouldn't believe it does. The heap size just says how much memory is assigned to the heap, not how memory the application is using in total.

Comment: Explain why the graphs on the linked page goes down. You can reproduce the tests locally....

Comment: The heap is just a portion of the  total memory used by the application.  Just because it not used by the heap doesn't mean the memory has returned to the OS. You would need to look at the free memory of the OS.

Comment: not releasing fre memory back to the OS should be a bug; see this http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4065018. This was raised in the starting releases of jdk.

Comment: Which is one of the key selling points of Azul's JVM. They claim they had to use a custom kernel in a virtualised machine because Windows and Linux did not have the support they needed to release memory back to the OS. i.e. its not simply a bug, nor can it be fixed easily. AFAIK No C program on Linux releases memory back to the OS (though some Windows programs do)

Comment: Azul needs to perform VM operations *extremely fast* (http://lwn.net/Articles/392745/). That's an entirely different story.

Comment: Azul no longer needs a custom kernel.  I now uses a memory driver.