# Where is my Java memory going?

Tags: java, memory, memory-leaks

I am running a JUnit test suite from Ant or Eclipse. PermGen is limited to 200 MB, heap to 1000 MB.

Java VisualVM reports allocated PermGen as 200 MB and allocated heap as 350 MB. That's 550 MB.

However, total virtual set size of this process is 2.5 GB, and resident set size is 1.8 GB. I understand there is supposed to be some overhead, but if PermGen and heap are 0.5 GB and the process is using 1.8 GB, where is the missing 1.3 GB? How can I diagnose and fix it?

Comment: Do you use any native libraries? Their native memory allocations will not show up in VisualVM. Also, is the process size the same without VisualVM?

Comment: No native libraries besides standard JVM from Sun. It's the same without VisualVM.

Comment: @Konrad are u using any memory analyzer tool to view ?

Comment: Ubuntu Linux, Java 6 from Sun.

Answer (score 0):

What is the heap free ratio? Are you using the default 70 and 40%. Maybe, there are garbage objects waiting to be collected by the next gc run. Also maybe the java process has allocated itself the extra memory (read about the heap free ratio).

Maybe the question/ answer/ comments mentioned at [Tuning Garbage Collection parameters in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180149/tuning-garbage-collection-parameters-in-java) offer some help.

Comment: I did not adjust or even know about this value. However, I start the process with -Xmx800m, and according to VisualVM it only allocated 350 MB and is using 50-70% of that. Even if it reserved 500 MB in advance, it still is far from 1300.

Comment: by default min heap free ratio is 40% and max free heap ratio is 70%; percentage in terms of the total heap size.

Comment: I have also updated my answer to point to another question which might be useful.

Answer (score -2):

Please check this [eclipse plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/) for memory analysis . Once you have installed this, it offers different views. In one [particular view](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/about/histogram.png), its shows the memory used by individual objects. This will help you to pinpoint the objects which are using the memory.

EDIT: I guess I missed the non-heap part.

Comment: How does that answer my question about non-heap memory?